# Webbrowser Control Replacement now that IE 11 has expired

Tags: vb.net, web, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I've been using the WebBrowser control for many years in VB Studio 2012 and 2015.
Now that IE 11 has been retired (which I assume was the engine behind the WebBrowser control), I understand that the WebView2 control for Edge is the recommended replacement.

Are they any other WebBrowser components that can be used in VB.Net/2012/2015 for example Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Comment: [Introduction to Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) -- Microsoft implementation of Chromium - CefSharp is another -  FireFox has its own engine. -- If you want to replace the WebBrowser control, WebView2 is probably a good choice (though still a work in progress, it's relatively stable <- i.e., good enough).

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I found an article on the subject: [Winform: How to add an embedded web browser (2020)](https://xinyustudio.medium.com/winform-how-to-add-an-embedded-web-browser-2019-7a5da106253d). The version of Gecko might be older than you want.